# Can data in a java text field be sent to jasper report without database interaction?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

We are developing a desktop application in java using netbeans. we have installed the jasper reports for netbeans and are able to design the reports from the data in the database

There is a form which we want to print without storing the data in the database. Can we send the form data into jasper report?

Please explain

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If it's just one value, you just have to set it in the parameters map of the report, and access it using `$P{foo}` (meaning the value is tored in the map, at the key `"foo"`). If it's a list of values you want to iterate on in the details band of the report, You may use a [`JRBeanCollectionDataSource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html).

You'll be able to access each property (throught its getter method) of the beans in the collection: `$F{foo}` will call your bean's `getFoo()` method to get the field value.

Comment: JB Nizet is right you can as stated ,and look samples under jasperreport distrubition demo/samples/    customdatasource example

Comment: @JB Nizet What if it's multiple values? like an entire JTable, after getting the strings displayed by the JTable you display them in the JasperReport, or is this impossible? because so far searching, it seems like the most obvious thing to do with a JasperReport is display any String of your choosing in the actual report, but searching through the net makes it like the least possible thing to do with a JasperReport. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

1. install IReport plugin in netbean IDE
2. Create Java Project and then create JavaBean class in this project
3. After clean and build project you to netbean menu Tool and go to
   Option after open option goto irepot tab and set classpath and add
   netbean JavaBean project Jar Path  Like if create Project HelloBean
   mean that jar name HelloBean.jar u your hellobean.jar and add it in
   your ireport class path.
4. after open your ireport you go!

check images here

[image: http://www.hrptech.com/download/step1.jpg]

[image: http://www.hrptech.com/download/step2.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

```
para.put(<key>,<value>);
para.put(<key>,<value>);
para.put(<key>,<value>);

JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jr, para, new JRemptyDataSource());
```

if you don't write  new JRemptyDataSource() a message will appear that the document has no pages 
and inside your report create a field and in field expression put your parameter (the parameter name should have the same key value )