# how to create a jasper report without database

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am creating a standard desktop application in which I need to create a report with *JasperReports*. I have a form designed, which takes the user's entry and should generate the *JR* report i.e. there is **no database** connectivity required.

I have seen in some similar question about parameters to be passed but it hasn't been of much help. There is a similar question here [Can data in a java text field be sent to jasper report without database interaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400317/can-data-in-a-java-text-field-be-sent-to-jasper-report-without-database-interact).

Please suggest a suitable method.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a database, you just set the values directly from your code, something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String sourceFileName =
  "C://tools/jasperreports-5.0.1/test/jasper_report_template.jasper";

  DataBeanList dataBeanList = new DataBeanList();
  ArrayList<DataBean> dataList = dataBeanList.getDataBeanList();

  JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource =
  new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);

  Map parameters = new HashMap();
  /**
   * Passing ReportTitle and Author as parameters
   */
  parameters.put("ReportTitle", "List of Contacts");
  parameters.put("Author", "Prepared By Manisha");

  try {
     JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(
     sourceFileName, parameters, beanColDataSource);
  } catch (JRException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Having for example this xml portion:

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
 <![CDATA[$P{ReportTitle}]]>
 </textFieldExpression>
 <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["Title"]]>
 </anchorNameExpression>
```

Comment: where is generated file location ?

Comment: What is DataBeanList? From which library is it?

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @WesosdeQueso DataBeanList would be your own repository class, and then DataBean would be your own POJO class representing your data.